# Install Shapely: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, package, shapely

I have to install Shapely package (http://toblerity.org/shapely/project.html#installation).
But when I am using:

```
pip install Shapely
```

I am getting this error:

```
Collecting Shapely
  Using cached Shapely-1.5.17.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mwuxcain\Shapely\setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mwuxcain\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos.dll")
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 344, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mwuxcain\Shapely\
```

And, when I am using:

```
conda install shapely
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '
```

I am using Python 3.6.0 (Anaconda3) on Windows 10 (64-bit).

Please help. (nothing works)

Comment: `conda install shapely` -- pip rarely works for things like this on windows

Comment: @PaulH Thanks. I have updated the question.

Comment: sorry, you might need to pull it from the conda-forge channel: `conda install shapely --channel=conda-forge`

Comment: @PaulH You could make that an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Download WHL file using http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely

Install:

```
python -m pip install Shapely-1.5.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Ubuntu:

```
pip install shapely==1.6b2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
conda install -c conda-forge shapely
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install shapely` was not working but
`conda install shapely` worked fine for me (windows user)

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me (Windows Server):

1. Install osgeo4w from https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
2. copy geos_c.dll and geos.dll to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Answer (score 0):

https://www.programmersought.com/article/70235795361/

```
copy "[env path]\LIb\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos*.dll" to "[env path]\Library\bin"
```

Comment: While the code might answer he question ,we cant trust the content in the link to do so. Could you append this answer with an explanation on what your snipped does?