# pip install osmnx giving error code 1

Tags: python, command-line, pip, osmnx

I am trying to install osmnx using the command

```
python -m pip install osmnx
```

but it gives the following error:

'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o3ha6gld\Shapely\'

Comment: Please give us the entire error output, not just part of one line.

Answer (score 1):

OSMnx installation instructions are provided in its documentation: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

conda installation is strongly recommended to avoid issues:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you need to download the wheel for that specific module and install separately:

[Install Shapely: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398265/install-shapely-oserror-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Then OSMnx will continue to install normally

Answer (score 0):

## Installation

You can install OSMnx with conda:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

Alternatively, you can run OSMnx + Jupyter directly from the official docker container, or you can install OSMnx via pip if you already have all of its dependencies installed and tested on your system. Note: pip installation is nontrivial. If you don’t know exactly what you’re doing, just use conda as described above.

To upgrade OSMnx to a newer release, just remove the conda environment you created and then create a new one again following the steps above. Don’t just run conda update or you could get package conflicts.