# error python setup.py egg_info when trying to install shapely

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, shapely

This happens when I try to install Shapely from pip.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\adami\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hws7cr7o\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\adami\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hws7cr7o\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\adami\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hws7cr7o\Shapely\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\adami\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hws7cr7o\Shapely\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\adami\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hws7cr7o\Shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\adami\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hws7cr7o\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you thouroughly read the instructions on the [_Shapely_ project page](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/)? Which one of the installation scenario presented in these instructions are you trying to follow?

Comment: Duplicate of [Install Shapely: OSError: \[WinError 126\] The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398265/install-shapely-oserror-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)